# Can import python package but not its modules

Tags: python, import, module, package, python-3.6

I'm writing a set of tools to be used in scripting and debugging, which I'm packaging. While I can import the package itself, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` whenever I try to import the modules in the package.

```
package_dir
│   README.md
│   setup.py   
│
└───package
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───utils
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   image_utils.py
│       │   ...
│   
└───...
```

**Installation:**
using `python setup.py install` seems to work fine, and I can successfully `import package`

**__init__.py:**
My understanding is that I don't need the __init__.py files since I'm running python3.6, but I've tried every combination with and without __init__.py under package/ and utils/, with no change in circumstances. Regardless of the configuration, `import package` works and I cannot import any modules.

**How I'm importing:**
I'm in a Jupyter notebook outside the package structure, and I've tried the following:

`import package`  (works)

`from package import utils`  (doesn't work: `ImportError`)

`from package.utils import image_utils` (doesn't work: `ModuleNotFoundError`)

`from package.utils.image_utils import func`  (doesn't work: `ModuleNotFoundError`)

I've also tried importing in the package's __init__.py using relative imports, with no success. I definitely don't want to use sys.path.insert() every time I want to use these tools.

I've scoured tutorials, documentation, and stack overflow. Anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: You don't need to put "(python 3.6)" in the title. It's available as a tag.

Comment: can you show us the contents of your__init__.py file?

Comment: @MFisherKDX the __init__.py file is currently empty but I've also tried nothing but a relative import of utils.image_utils

Comment: Try this: 1. `import package` 2. `print(dir(package))`. Is everything there?

Comment: @s3n0 No, everything is not there. None of the modules are there. Output is just: ['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__']

Comment: And what about `import package.utils` or `import package.utils.image_utils` ? Does not work ? I.e. without usage the `from` to specify some classes or methods from module. Try adding a hashtag to the top of all files - if it's not there: `#!/usr/bin/python` but that probably won't help. If you run Python 3.6 code on a Linux system, finding the right path can be more complex. You can try shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Comment: There is a little difference in the Linux system if you start the python code through the Shell command line as a script. It is necessary to supervise access paths from the root directory where Python is installed on Linux and also on your file attributes: `chmod -R +x *.py`. There is also a difference if you start the code through a Python interpreter in Linux. In my opinion the problem will be in any of the above. Simply put, Python behaves differently when looking for a relative path on Linux vs Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a previous version (without proper __init__.py files in all module directories or import statements in the package's __init__.py) was preventing my latest install from being recognized.

To fix this, I first tried to remove all files created during install:
`python setup.py install --record installfiles.txt`

But this didn't actually show me everything that I needed to remove.

1. I also removed the build and cached files within the package: build/, package/, dist/, and .egg-info/ (as well as all caches)
2. Then I removed the site package: /anaconda3/envs/[env_name]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/[package_name]
3. And removed the package from the easy-install .pth: /anaconda3/envs/[env_name]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy_install.pth
4. And the .egg-info: /anaconda3/envs/[env_name]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/[package-name].egg-info

This allowed me to install properly. Thanks to everyone for the help!